# Python script to run a ping command with URL parameter

Tags: python

I am trying to build a little script that helps me ping hosts by using a python script via browser.

I am stuck and I need some advice. I am new to python.

Bellow is the code I have written so far...

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import os.path
import urlparse

print('Content-type: text/html\r\n\r')

url = os.environ['HTTP_HOST']
uri = os.environ['REQUEST_URI']
link = url + uri

print("<br>\n{}\n<br>".format(link))

parsed = urlparse.urlparse(link)
theparameter = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['name']
thehost = (theparameter)[0]

print("===============\n{}\n===============".format(thehost))

print("<br>")
os.system("ping -c 4 {}".format(thehost))
# print("<br>")
```

In the apache error logs I have the following error:

```
malformed header from script 'test.py': Bad header: PING <theIPaddress> (<theIPaddress>)
```

Thank you!

Later edit: I found a solution to my question.

```
check = ("ping -c 4 {}".format(thehost))
result = os.popen(check).read()

print "<pre>"
print result
print "</pre>"
```

Comment: Are you against using a build in python library instead of the system ping?

Comment: Could you please give me more details? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For simple ping I use this simple call and it works fine:

```
def ping(hostname):
    return os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname) == 0


print("8.8.8.8")
```

Output:

```
True
```